# Select multiple elements from python array

Tags: python

How can I select multiple elements from a python array? I know that this is possible in numpy array but I cannot use numpy array in this case. I want to select certain elements of an array similar to masked array usage but i get following error in python

```
 nonzero = numpyarray.nonzero()
 pythonarray[nonzero] = numpyarray[nonzero]
 *** TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

`numpyarray[nonzero]` works fine but I cannot access `pythonarray[nonzero]`. Is there a way to do this in python array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a loop:

```
for idx in nonzero:
    pythonarray[idx] = numpyarray[idx]
```

Numpy arrays probably support n-ary indices to maximize performance; Python lists don't go that far with optimisations so you have to use the simpler approach.

Comment: Thanks. I guess this will slow down the performance a lot. I have to do this 1 million times. And oh btw, it should be `idx` in the assignment expression instead of `nonzero`

Comment: @Alok: do you really have to use a Python array? maybe can your problem be solved with a more efficient structure??

Comment: @EOL could you advice? The reason I am using array is because I am building an array after reading a text file which contains about a million lines or more. I have to extend array after reading each line by adding 30 elements to it. Extending an array dynamically is not very efficient in numpy arrays and hence I am using python arrays. I could instead allocate certain storage for numpy array and reallocate when its filled, but there is no appromiate storage space that I can use.

Comment: @Alok If you need to do something a million times quickly, Python in general might not be a good choice. (If you can't keep this in C code using numpy.)

Comment: @Alok: Are you sure that Python lists resize faster than numpy arrays? As far as I know Python lists are backed by C arrays, so they have to be reallocated and possibly copied as well. If you need to grow efficiently to a large size without a reasonable upper bound, I'd consider using some sort of C-based linked list implementation to get rid of all the reallocations.

Comment: @Alok Also, if every line has exactly 30 elements, what you could do is have a Python / linked list of 30-element numpy arrays, one per line. (The IO cost should dominate the overhead of a linked list.) Once you read the whole file, you know how many elements there are. You could then either create one huge numpy array for the result and copy stuff over once from the list, or just use the list-of-arrays directly. (Which one is better depends on your use case.)

Comment: (Disclaimer: the above is mostly conjecture based on what you think is the reason for a slowdown. As always, if you care about performance, you should profile over a realistic dataset before optimising.)

Comment: @Alok: you could ask a separate question about how to read  millions lines appending 30 elements afterwards efficiently (provide a small working example even if it is too slow).

Comment: @millimoose: there are other options to try before implementing your own resizable arrays in C

Comment: @millimoose I will try your suggestions and post the results in a separate question.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Probably, I admit it's the nuclear option; there's probably more to be gained by reducing copying and the overhead of manipulating data structures in Python. (Working over lists instead of elements etc.)