# choosing multiple element in python list

Tags: python, list

How can i choose random multiple elements from list ? I looked it from internet but couldn't find anything.

```
words=["ar","aba","oto","bus"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select multiple elements from python array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273495/select-multiple-elements-from-python-array)

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve that with `random.sample()`:

```
from random import sample

words = ["ar", "aba", "oto", "bus"]
selected = sample(words, 2)
```

That would select 2 words randomly from the words list.
You can check Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) for more details.

Comment: No worries, mate! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think about that :

```
import random as rd
words=["ar","aba","oto","bus"]
random_words = [word for word in words if rd.random()>1/2]
```

You can adjust 1/2 by any value between 0 and 1 to approximate the percentage of words chosen in the initial list.

Answer (score 0):

Use `random`

Here is example

- `random.choice`

```py
>>> import random
>>> words=["ar","aba","oto","bus"]
>>> print(random.choice(words))
ar
>>> print(random.choice(words))
ar
>>> print(random.choice(words))
oto
>>> print(random.choice(words))
aba
>>> print(random.choice(words))
ar
>>> print(random.choice(words))
bus
```

- `random.sample` # sample takes one extra argument to pass a list with element is returned

```py
>>> print(random.sample(words, 3))
['bus', 'ar', 'oto']
>>> print(random.sample(words, 3))
['ar', 'oto', 'aba']
>>> print(random.sample(words, 2))
['aba', 'bus']
>>> print(random.sample(words, 2))
['ar', 'aba']
>>> print(random.sample(words, 1))
['ar']
>>> print(random.sample(words, 1))
['ar']
>>> print(random.sample(words, 1))
['oto']
>>> print(random.sample(words, 1))
['bus']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random` library

**Method 1 - random.choice()**

```py
from random import choice

words=["ar","aba","oto","bus"]
word = choice(words)
print(word)
```

**Method 2 - Generate Random Index**

```py
from random import randint

words=["ar","aba","oto","bus"]
ind = randint(0, len(words)-1)
word = words[ind]
print(word)
```

**Method 3 - Select Multiple Items**

```py
from random import choices

words=["ar","aba","oto","bus"]
selected = choices(words, k=2)   # k is the elements count to select
print(selected)
```